# React responsive orinetation prop starts as null

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-responsive in react project.

**Problem:**

Orientation prop is always null, so the app is not displayed well.

**Question:**

I would want to know how to trigger some event that checks and set orientation to react responsive prop or any solution. I think that there's a problem calculating the initial resolution.

**More:**

I can set initialMediaType parameter to small instead of default in order to get no initial problems when I am using a mobile browser.

Comment: Can you please post the code snippet? Our community might be able to find something you are missing, else given that this library doesn't seem to be so widely used, opening a github issue may be the way to go.

Comment: thx, this is a better way to find a solution.